# Securesocial play 2.3 master - update user

Tags: scala, securesocial

I added securesocial 2.3 to my project and it works well. SecuredAction offers easy user access (`request.user`) and everything is fine until properties of my user change. I have no idea how to tell the securesocial that the users fields have updated or how to give him different user object to associate with.

How can I do that or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks, 
Lovro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 2.3 version of SecureSocial. I assume you are using Play 2.3 and master-SNAPSHOT or 3.0-M1 here.

Once a user is authenticated SecureSocial uses an Authenticator to keep track of the user session.  The module has 2 built in authenticators: CookieAuthenticator and HttpHeaderAuthenticator. Both implementations extend StoreBackedAuthenticator which uses an AuthenticatorStore to save/retrieve instances of the authenticators.

The default store implementation uses a CacheService.  So if you change properties of your users and want those reflected you need to invoke something like the following:

```
val updatedUser = <some code that changes your user>
request.authenticator.updateUser(updatedUser)
```

Comment: You are correct, it is play 2.3 master SNAPSHOT.  

I already tried  
`request.authenticator.updateUser(updatedUser)`  

once before, but it didn't work. I'll try it again tommorow.  

Thanks

Comment: How can I do this with the Java API?